# 'Natural' drag and drop with reparenting

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I would like to drag an item ('drag') from one div ('original') to another ('target') and have the div be re-parented to the target div.

I would like for 'drag', on re-parenting, to land right where it is positioned.  (You are pulling a sticker off div one and placing it onto div two: when I mouse up it lands right where it is).

When I try this with the code below, 'drag' positions itself in 'target' based on its position relative to 'original'.  e.g. if 'drag' is (300, 300) off of 'original' when I drop it, on re-parenting it will go to (300, 300) off 'target' (which causes a jump b/c 'target' and 'original' don't have same upper left corner).

Long-term the 'original' div may be fairly complicated (e.g. a scrolling panel of stickers, or tabs or whatever) so I don't want some kind of trickery where it just looks like 'drag' starts in 'original'.

I have experimented with doing some kind of complex math-fu based on global position of 'target' and 'drop' when I am dropping, but 1) that is a pain to get right in the face of margins, padding, scaling, etc) and 2) I would think this would be easier.  It seems like it's a fairly basic expectation, that an item stays where it is dropped.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Drop</title>

    <script src="libraries/javascript/third_party/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libraries/javascript/third_party/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

      $(document).ready(function() {
          var $dest = $('#destinationDiv');
          var $src = $('#originalDiv');
          var $drag = $('#draggableDiv');

          $dest.droppable({accept: '#draggableDiv',
                  drop: function(event, ui) {
                    $dest.append(ui.draggable);
                  },
                  tolerance: 'fit',
          });
          $drag.draggable({appendTo: '#destinationDiv',
           // helper: 'clone',
            revert: 'invalid',
            revertDuration: 100,
          });
      });

    </script>

    <style>
        #destinationDiv {
            position:absolute;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background: #cccccc;
            border:solid;
            top: 50px;
            left: 50px;
        }
        #originalDiv {
            position:absolute;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            top: 30px;
            left: 30px;
            background: #ddccff;
            border:solid;
        }
        #draggableDiv {
            position:absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            top: 10px;
            left: 10px;
            background: #ccffdd;
            border:solid;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id=destinationDiv>
    <div id=originalDiv>
        <div id=draggableDiv></div>
    <div>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sKnsp/

Comment: Like this? hardcoded for now, but the offset correction could be calculated. http://jsfiddle.net/sKnsp/1/

Comment: small update: http://jsfiddle.net/sKnsp/2/

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response.  Yes, that is the behavior I want.  I am not sure where the 34 came from though.  I known that 'original' is 30 off of 'drop', and I guess the other 4 come from border somehow.  Once I am in a more dynamic situation I guess I will just have to clown around with the positioning to figure it all out.  Specifically if 'drag' were in a scroll widget inside of 'original'.

Comment: It actually works best with 33, but i can explain 34 by the 2px border.

Comment: Thanks to Kevin for response. I think the key thing I was missing was the notion of the 'helper' and the 'draggable' in 'ui' while things are being dragged and when they are dropped. 'Position' of helper was exactly what I wanted.

Cleaned up some other stuff, added colors to make it clear what's up, using procedural measurements for everything, using a scroller for multiple stickers, etc.

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/dougbanks/X7j5u/

Good times.